# How to put together two application.yml configs of two projects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have two projects. One is just a client¹ that does http request to an external service. The other is a Rest API.

The client¹ reads an url configured in its own `application.yml`, but when I add a dependency (through pom.xml) to this client in the Rest API project, it no longer reads that property (it is null).

I want it to read from its own application.yml, so that I have a default value (that can be overridden later if necessary). How can I do that?

---

¹ The client is defined like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app.client.notification")
public class NotificationClient { 
    private String url; // comes from application.yml.
                        // Works fine in the client project,
                        // and DOESN'T in the Rest project
}
```

Comment: The client's `application.yml` won't be loaded by spring-boot per default inside the rest API application. You need to specifically load it.

Comment: @JeremyGrand how can I do that?

Comment: I think you can achieve something using spring.config.location but I don't have time to try & write a proper solution. I hope you'll manage somehow

Comment: @Fabricio you need to explicitly define the location of that .yml file somewhere in the code a'la **@PropertySource("classpath:/application.yml")**. I don't know about naming conflicts though, you need to experiment with it yourself.

Comment: @rorschach that worked, I just had to use another name like `myprojname.yml`. Would you mind to reply so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the location of that .yml file somewhere in the code a'la **@PropertySource("classpath:/application.yml")**. I don't know about naming conflicts though, you need to experiment with it yourself.